# Best way for connecting this redstone vertically?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-redstone

i am currently working on a big RAM in minecraft and i want to connect the inputs of each row vertically: [image]

I want to connect the yellow lines. It should be fast not use too much space.

Comment: Use half slabs. They don't cut vertical Redstone

Comment: But redstone only goes 15 blocks. My thing here is about 128 blocks high!

Comment: Yes you will need repeaters, but it's still cheaper than some alternatives.

Comment: If you don't mind the signal going only up or only down, you can use the torch-block sequence, this is self-powering.

Comment: how should i get it with torches DOWN? i dont want to get as many as possible ticks. i need a fast connection from the top floor down.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If low latency is more important than space, you can go straight up in a mostly 1x2 space, with a small section of 2x3:

[image: Ignore the house]

If space is more important than low latency, you can replace the repeater with a vertical double NOT gate, which would lower the maximum space from 2x3 to 1x3:

[image]

Comment: I am still working on my project and now I need it from top to bottom. Any cool idea?

Comment: The first picture can travel downwards if you reverse the repeater's direction. Since the second pic's double NOT gate can't travel downward, the first pic is likely going to be your best bet.

Answer (score 4):

I finally got it like this:
[image: The solution]
Every second floor is a repeater with two redstonetorches (idea from [[Russ Whitchurch]](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/users/27903/russ-whitchurch) [here](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/124868/52074))

Answer (score 1):

If it is just down I use a dispenser into a block(connected to a Piston) then a piston fires releasing it and it falls onto a pressure plate on top of a fence (at the bottom)!