# How can I get this setup to work properly?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-redstone

I have a setup in a space-station with which I want an airlock with two doors: door X & door Y.

I've remade this setup in the Overworld in a smaller fashion to show you how I've got it set up which you can see here:

[image: Door circuit]

Before clicking the button (which is located on the back of the gold block behind the pistons), door X is open and door Y is closed, just making sure you don't confuse them :P)

This is supposed to close door X before opening door Y, after which it closes door Y before opening door X.

Although now it's closing door X, a few ticks later it opens door Y, but then it switches them around just about simultaneously again.

I've tried using a T-flip flop instead of this configuration, but that proves to be a bit too laggy on a multiplayer server (the doors bugged out by opening & closing repeatedly even though I only had a single pulse as input)

How can I get this to work as intended without using up TOO much space?

Update: I just thought of another possibility, which is making the button work like a lever (in my case by using pistons) and having 2 seperate outputs which are being toggled with different timings on each output, which works perfectly.

Now another question arises, if this is the way to do this, how do i get it to repeat itself once (so it works exactly the way I want it) without having to press the button again?

[image: New circuit]

Comment: If possible you should mark up your picture so the components are more clear. Labeling which door is which is sufficient.

Comment: Just added the info & marked up the image :)

Comment: Great first question, +1

Comment: To repeat itself, you can just use a loop of repeaters off the button press, so they re-inject that signal back as if the button were pressed again after the desired delay. There's probably a more elegant method, but that one is simple.

Comment: That would be the solution if that didn't mean it'd just keep on repeating itself indefinately. What I'm looking for would be something which only triggers the output twice (in total, including the initial button press)

Comment: ^ Never mind, I used my tired brain and figured out a way to only make it repeat itself once by using an extra repeater after the button triggers the loop >.> i'm an idiot sometimes :>

Comment: Not an idiot: that's clever debugging. :)

Comment: @yorrick good job, now post what you did as an answer and in two days you can accept it.

Comment: I love Minecraft redstone questions like these. Definitely post your answer; I'm excited to see the solution to this in greater detail.

Comment: I'll record a video of it & upload it as an answer, probably going 2 be the most detailed possible answer :) Give me about an hour to record, edit & upload it ;)

Comment: Btw SevenSidedDie, my excuse:  it being 8am & not having slept all night :3 & @Gigazelle, you love minecraft redstone questions like what exactly? How would you categorise this question? (Just curious :3)

Comment: Questions like this that present a genuine problem: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/124727/best-way-for-connecting-this-redstone-vertically/124868#124868 - i like seeing these kinds of questions, as redstone is something that fascinates me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Figured it out after a while & had some help from @SevenSidedDie for having the circuit repeat itself once & only once per button press :)

Uploaded a video of the circuit & it's operation.

Thanks to everyone for giving a hand at solving this (or at least trying :) )

Video: